# How one could make a package that does not conflict with others?

Tags: packages

I am working on the construction of a music package and I would like to have new commands with short names for clarity... So for example I use `\bar`, `\k`, `\arg` but they are already defined in `LaTeX` Is there some trick so that all these commands could be used at least locally with the way I like?

In other words, Is it possible to define some special commands inside my package let say `\mypackageON`and `\mypackageOFF` so that if I encolse a text with the above start-end commands no broblem will arise with the use of `\bar` etc? Is there a better strategy? Excuse me for this general question...

Comment: You could provide an environment called, say, `mypackage` which redefines `\arg`, `\bar`, etc. That way, the scope of the redefinitions ends with `\end{mypackage}`.

Comment: You could look e.g. at siunitx where all unit definitions are "active" only inside the \si/\Si-commands.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher Do you know how these commands si and Si are defined?  How one could avoid a conflict using a command like\si{a long text with my  coomands.....} There must a mechanism for activation and diactivation!

Comment: @kornaros -- Have a look at the user guide of the `siunitx` package to learn how `\si` and `\SI` are defined. :-)

Comment: @Mico I have already looked. I don't find where \si is defined. This package has 101 pages. I just want  to have some idea  how si is defined so that it could accept any new definition without  the risk of name clashes! Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @kornaros - Do check out section 4.3, "Units", on pages 7 and 8 of the user guide for the definitions of `\si` and `\SI`.

Answer (score 8):

You could provide an environment called, say, `myenv`, which redefines `\arg`, `\bar`, etc. That way, the scope of the redefinitions automatically ends with `\end{myenv}`.

A simple working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Enable "\k" ("ogonek") macro

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
   % Provide (re)definitions of \arg, \bar, etc
   \def\arg{...}
   \def\bar{...}
   \def\k{...}}{}

\begin{document}
$\arg a$, $\bar{b}$, \k{c}

\begin{myenv}
\arg a, \bar{b}, \k{c}
\end{myenv}

$\arg a$, $\bar{b}$, \k{c}
\end{document}
```

---

Here's a version that uses "switches" -- named `\mypackageON` and `\mypackageOFF` -- instead of an environment. As per the suggestion made by Ulrike in a comment, the code first saves the original versions of `\arg`, `\bar` etc, and the new macros are given "music" prefixes. Then, `\mypackageON` activates the music-related versions of the macros, and `\mypackageOFF` activates the original versions of the macros. (`\LetLtxMacro` is used instead of `\let`, just in case some of the commands being redefined take optional arguments and/or were declared to be "robust".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Enable "\k" macro ("ogonek")

% Save the old versions of the macros
\usepackage{letltxmacro} % for "\LetLtxMacro" command
\LetLtxMacro\origarg\arg
\LetLtxMacro\origbar\bar
\LetLtxMacro\origk\k

% Define some new macros
\newcommand\musicarg[1]{#1} % "#1" just regurgitates the argumenet
\newcommand\musicbar[1]{#1}
\newcommand\musick[1]{#1}

\newcommand\mypackageON{% enable the music-related versions
   \LetLtxMacro\arg\musicarg
   \LetLtxMacro\bar\musicbar
   \LetLtxMacro\k\musick}

\newcommand\mypackageOFF{% enable the original versions
   \LetLtxMacro\arg\origarg
   \LetLtxMacro\bar\origbar
   \LetLtxMacro\k\origk}

\begin{document}
$\arg a$, $\bar{b}$, \k{c}

\mypackageON
\arg a, \bar{b}, \k{c}

\mypackageOFF
$\arg a$, $\bar{b}$, \k{c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The idea is very good. But the only problem is when I use a lot of \begin{myenv} \end{myenv} Is it better to make a switch like \mypackageON and \mypackageOFF where in the first  case I save the commands to other names .eg. \argoriginal and in the other command I redefine the arg command using \argoriginal? What is your opinion?

Comment: @kornaros - I think it would be helpful if you gave some specific examples of what the redefined macros `\arg`, `\bar`, etc are supposed to achieve. (Warning: Sadly, I know exceedingly little about musicological notation.)

Comment: These commands are very simple indeed. For axample, \bar calls a symbol from a specific font using   the command  \char" + hex number. I do not like to change this name to someting like \musicbar or similar. because bar is a very common music term! The use of the enviroments has only one danger like \begin{myenv} \begin{myenv} \end{myenv} Because of the nested myenv if one forget the last \end{myenv} then the he will have a problem. So I suggest that it is beter to use "switchers" like \mypackageON and \mypackageOFF. Is it good idea, or it is better to use an enviroment?

Comment: @kornaros: He would also have a problem if he forgets \mypackageOFF and unlike with environment there would be perhaps no warning. Beside this: I wouldn't use \def in the environment, but outside do something like `\newcommand\myspecialarg{...}` and inside `\let\arg\myspecialarg`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think you are right! It is better to let the LaTeX do the ckeck for us! Thanks!

Comment: @kornaros - I've provided an addendum that follows up on Ulrike's suggestion and sets up two "switches", named `\mypackageON` and `\mypackageOFF`. (I'm sure you'll be able to come up with more mnemonic names for the switching macros.)

Comment: @Mico Yes! Switches are more preferable to me, no braces no begin-end. Thaks for this nice improvement of your answer!